# Two elements of the quotient $S/{\sim} $ are equal if and only if the corresponding elements in $S$ are related by $\sim$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, equivalence-relations

This was in the book I was studying from so I went to prove it just for the sake of further understanding it, although it wasn't an exercise so I can't really go anywhere to check if my proof is correct. This is my first time working with equivalent relations so I'd really like to get some insight.

> Two elements of the quotient $S/{\sim}$ are equal if and only if the corresponding elements in $S$ are related by $\sim$.

Let $A,B,a,b \in S$, and
\begin{align*}
S/{\sim} \  &:= \{[A]_\sim , \ [B]_\sim, \ \dots \},\\
[A]_\sim \ &:=\{ a \in S \mid a \sim A\},\\
[B]_\sim \ &:=\{ b \in S \mid b \sim B\}.
\end{align*}

If $a \sim A$, $b \sim B$, and $a \sim b$, then because $\sim$ is transitive and symmetric, $a \sim b \to a \sim B$ so $a \in [B]_\sim$ and $b \sim a \to b \sim A$ so $b \in [A]_\sim$.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are heading the right way. This is how I will do it, first let's translate into maths your statement:

> $[A]_\sim=[B]_\sim$ if and only if $A\sim B$

Now we can just work with your definitions.

> 1) Assume $[A]_\sim=[B]_\sim$ then, $A\in [A]_\sim$ implies $A\in [B]_\sim$, which then implies $A\sim B$.
>
> 2) Assume $A\sim B$ then you have to prove an equality of sets, so one inclusion and then the other.
>
> Take $a\in[A]_\sim$, that means $a\sim A$ and now you can use transitivity and  $A\sim B$, to get $a\sim B$ which means $a\in[B]_\sim$
>
> So you have $[A]_\sim\subseteq[B]_\sim$ and the other inclusion is similar.

Comment: Oh, thats much better! I was also unsure of how to show the converse, so thank you for indicating your method :)

Comment: If you want to be really strict to prove that other inclusion you will need the symmetry apart from the transitivity.

Comment: I was actually writing down the proof in my notebook and when I was showing $b \sim B$ implies $b \sim A$ I made sure to indicate usage of the symmetry property! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are only showing the "if" part of the equivalence; so you need to write the "only if" part for it to be complete. Also, your notation $a \sim A$ should be $a \in [A]_\sim$, since equivalence classes are sets. I would prove this result as follows:

For any $x \in S$, we have $x \sim x$ (reflexivity), so $\{ a \in S \mid a \sim x \}$ is not empty (it contains at least $x$). So we can take a shorter notation for equivalence classes, and write for example $\dot{x}$ to denote the equivalence class of the element $x$.

Taking $y \in \dot{x}$, we have by definition of $\dot{x}$, $x \sim y$. For any $z \in S$ such that $y \sim z$, the transitivity of $\sim$ allows us to conclude that $x \sim z$. From this we conclude that $\dot{y} \subset \dot{x}$. We can switch the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the above to get the reverse inclusion $\dot{x} \subset \dot{y}$. We have shown that $\forall x,y \in S,\; x \sim y \implies \dot{x} = \dot{y}$

For the converse, take $x$ and $y$ such that $\dot{x} = \dot{y}$. Since $\dot{x}$ is not empty, take an element $z \in \dot{x}$. Such a $z$ verifies $x \sim z$. Since $\dot{x} = \dot{y}$, $z$ is also an element of $\dot{y}$, and so $y \sim z$. The symmetry of $\sim$ shows that $z \sim y$, and then the transitivity of $\sim$ allows us to conclude that $x \sim y$. We have shown that $\forall \dot{x}, \dot{y} \in S/\sim,\; \dot{x} = \dot{y} \implies x \sim y$